# Unable to acheive desired effect with ID mask

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I'm trying to make the render have an effect where the stars (which are exploded fragments) have a glowing glare-like effect and the other objects (i.e. film reel and cubes) are their natural colors.  However, despite having made the star objects all a pass index of 1 and the rest 0 by default, everything seems to render a green glowing effect that's supposed to be only for the objects with a pass index of 1.  To illustrate:

This is the render of the image naturally (I rendered at very low quality but it's just for demonstration purposes):

[image: raw render]

And this is with the composite nodes:

[image: composited image and nodes]

So in essence I want the objects in the the first render I showed to keep those colors, but the stars to have the colors of the green glowing effect.  As you can see from the 2nd picture everything has the green effect.

My node setup is pretty big so I will provide a link to download the **[.blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzCN0fElYa3Ha1FGZ1JBTnJ6M3M/view?usp=sharing)** so you can see the nodes more clearly.