# ID Mask won't render composite properly

Tags: compositing-nodes

I've been trying like crazy to get my composite node setup to render the exploding objects (pass index 1) and I really can't understand why my ID Mask won't render them.  Instead it renders the entire thing in a bluish green hue.  I just want the objects with a pass index of 1 to look like that.  It's been difficult to get any answers via pictures since my node setup is pretty big so I will provide a link to download the .blend file so you can see the nodes more clearly.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzCN0fElYa3Ha1FGZ1JBTnJ6M3M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: it this the same question as: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47510/unable-to-acheive-desired-effect-with-id-mask ?